# Can't paste screenshot on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, screenshot, paste

I'm using ubunto 20.04. I try to take a screenshot and paste into a document in LibreOffice but it don't work. Although all images are saved.
If I use `Ctrl + PrntScrn`, it work. But I want more, like `Prnt Scrb` (quickly), `Shift + Prnt Scrn` (select area) or `Alt + Prnt Scrn`(window).

Thanks.

Comment: In 20.04 I used `Ctrl+Print Scrn` to capture a window and then used `Ctrl V` to paste it to a LibreOffice Writer document so you question doesn't make sense. Perhaps you can [edit] your question to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

> If I use Ctrl + PrntScrn, it work

That is exactly how you must do it if you want the screenshot to be copied to the clipboard instead of saved to a file.

You can customize the system to work differently.

- If you rather want <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> to copy to the clipboard instead of to a file, change the keyboard bindings for screenprint in Settings - Keyboard Shortcuts, "Screenshots" section.
- If you rather want the tool to output *both* to the clipboard and to a file, delete the default assignment of <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> under the "Screenshots" section, and define your own keybinding to <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> under the "Custom Shortcuts" section. The command is `gnome-screenshots` with the options to both save to the clipboard and to a file, e.g. as in

  ```
  gnome-screenshot -c -f "/home/<yourlogin>/Pictures/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")"
  ```

Then, hitting <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> automatically will save both to the clipboard and a file, like it does by default in Ubuntu 22.04.